# Can a domain be set to auto renew at the end of the 10 year registration period?

Tags: domains

I have several domains that I’ve set to auto renew yearly.  Next month, I’ll have owned these domains for a full 10 years, which is how long I originally registered them for.

I want to continue to own these domains for the next 10 years. Can I set them to auto renew at the end of this year even though it’s the very last year of the 10 year registration period, or do I have to manually do it this year? Basically I want to make sure that the auto renewal, which has worked fine for the last 9 years will work again this year.

Comment: Any "auto renew" process is dependent on your domain registrar. However, your question is not clear. You say that these domains were "set to auto renew yearly", yet you registered them for a "10 year registration period"? Were they registered for 10 years? Or were they registered for 1 year and set to auto-renew each year for 10 years?!

Comment: I think it's pretty clear as is: bought 10 years ago with annual renewal. OP wonders if the 10 year limit is per renewal or total lifespan.

Comment: I don’t think it is all that clear actually.  Did he register them for 10 years or has been renewing them annually each year for the past ten years?

Answer (score 2):

There is no change of operations after 10 years.

I suspect you are talking about gTLDs. The only rule there is that a domain name expiration date can not be more than 10 years in the future. But it says nothing about how often the domain name was auto-renewed and how old it is.

So your auto-renewal procedure, whatever it is, will work as is for the 10th to 11th year, then 11 to 12, and so on.

But this question seems overly specific to the registrar you use (you do not say) and depends on your domain, specifically its TLD (you do not say).

Note that in gTLDs, and in some ccTLDs, you can do explicit renewals at any time, for up to 10 years, and same for registration. So you can today renew your domain name for 10 years (or less, depending on your current expiration date, there is a rule - in gTLDs, sometimes in ccTLDs too - where the current expiration date can never be more than 10 years in the future).

Answer (score 1):

The rules only say the domain can only have 10 years of registration on it, not that you can't own it for longer than 10.  Your auto renew should work as you expect it to (renewing x # of days before expiration), you don't have to do it manually